# How do you compare analysis of two projects in SonarQube 7?

Tags: sonarqube, code-metrics

Currently using SonarQube 7.2 LGPL v3 Community.
Branching has not been provided in community edition,it is a paid plugin for developer addition so that is not an option.

I simply want to see LOC of two projects as a chart.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature out of the box in SonarQube. You can use measures web API ([example here](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/measures)) to retrieve the metrics you want and create the chart yourself for example in a spreadsheet.